# Prove $(p\to q)\land(p\to\neg q)\iff\neg p$

Tags: logic

How can I prove $(p\to q)\land(p\to\neg q)\iff\neg p$?

Comment: Prove it how???

Comment: The title says "equivalent" but in the text there is no equivalence...

Comment: What does it mean "with Deductive way"?

Comment: i mean not with table truth. prove it with out table truth

Comment: yes . thank you J.G.

Comment: Hint: rewrite $p\to q$ as $\neg p\lor q$ etc., then use the law of the excluded middle for $q$.

Comment: can u explain a bit more please , i dont understand yet

Comment: Hello, there might be a symbols confusion later, so it's grammatically correct or more convenient in logic (first order logic) to write "$\Rightarrow \text{or} \implies$" instead of "$\rightarrow$"

Comment: can u write an  example of it?

Comment: @yghboy Yes, but please tag the user you are commenting to.

Comment: @SubGenius .sorry im new to this

Comment: @ygh In general there are some uses of $\rightarrow$ and other logical symbols that might mean different things, for example if you studied real analysis, you know that limit (mathematical operation) have many uses of $\rightarrow$, it's just symbolic definition of a limit but still it might confuse you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\;p\to q\;$ is TRUE if and only if $p$ is FALSE or $q$ is TRUE and since $\;p\to\neg q\;$ is TRUE if and only if $p$ is FALSE or $\neg q$ is TRUE, then

$(p\to q)\land(p\to\neg q)\iff(\lnot p\lor q)\land(\lnot p\lor\lnot q)$

By applying the distributive property of OR with respect to AND, we get that

$(\lnot p\lor q)\land(\lnot p\lor\lnot q)\iff
(\lnot p)\lor(q\color{blue}{\pmb{\land}}\lnot q)$

But $\;q\color{blue}{\pmb{\land}}\lnot q\;$ is always FALSE, consequently

$(\lnot p)\lor(q\color{blue}{\pmb{\land}}\lnot q)\iff(\lnot p)\lor\color{blue}{FALSE}$

Finally,

$(\lnot p)\lor\color{blue}{FALSE}\iff \lnot p$

Comment: thank you so much
@angelo

Comment: for those who dont know . u have to factor this out ~pV

Answer (score 0):

$(p\to q)\land(p\to\neg q)\iff \\
(\lnot p \lor q)\land (\lnot p \lor \lnot q) \iff\\
(\lnot p)\lor(q \land \lnot q) \iff \\
(\lnot p)\lor FALSE \iff \lnot p$

Comment: thank you . can anyone explain the second line ?
(¬p∨q)∧(¬p∨¬q) what hapend to it .

Comment: @Angelo.can u please explain these steps ?

Comment: @yghboy Yup, you're right, i made a mistake there. Fixed now.